# How to dispose IE when form is closed?

Tags: c#, watin, dispose

I've been looking for an answer to this problem, but couldn't find it anywhere.

I have written an app that utilizes Watin. It works fine, apart from the problem that if I click the "X" button to close the app BEFORE Watin completes all of the actions (before it's disposed, I guess), it doesn't close. My app is still running (although the form is no longer there), as well as all of the IE instances.

I guess I should use FormClosing event handler to kill Watin, but since I'm utilizing the using statement, I've no idea how to achieve that.
Here's a piece of code I'm using:

```
using (var newBrowser = new IE("http://address.com"))
{
   AnalyzeTools FormActions = new AnalyzeTools(progressBar, labelProgress, labelProgressOutOf, richBoxKeywords.Lines.Count());

   Analyzer Analytic = new Analyzer(newBrowser, richBoxKeywords.Lines.ToList<string>(), FormActions);
   BeingAnalyzed = Analytic;

   Analytic.Initialize(textBoxLogin.Text, textBoxPass.Text);
   Analytic.HandleAnalysis();
}
```

**EDIT:**
OK, I did some more trouble-shooting and this is what I've come up with:
The app is working until all it's finished, simple as that. But it doesn't finish "properly", though -- it crashes, because it can't access the form which no longer exists.

I believe I could fix this by creating a FormClosing or FormClosed event that when triggered, would modify the behaviour of my app. A custom "exit" method. But still, I won't be terminating Watin (something I want to do) and the app would be still running.

The thing is, I don't really need it to accomplish all of the actions it's supposed to.

Is my idea of termination a good one? And is there a way to terminate Watin without dropping the using-statement idea?

**EDIT 2:**
OK, I tried a few new things.
I created that messagebox which asks for a decision. I tried using Application.Exit() to terminate, but it doesn't work as I hoped it would. The app's vshost is still running (WatiN?).
So I guess my question comes to this: is the only way to terminate WatiN to drop the using statement, make the IE object available everywhere in the class and dispose it when the user chooses to terminate it?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to do is create an instance of IE and then just close that instance. When you need it again you can just recreate the instance. I found this on Stackoverflow a long time ago when I had a similiar problem but I couldn't find it again to link to it.

```
public sealed class BrowserIE
{

    static readonly IE _Instance = new IE();

    static BrowserIE()
    {}

    BrowserIE()
    { }

    public static IE Instance
    {
        get { return _Instance; }
    }
}
```

create a class with the code above. use

```
var browser = BrowserIE.Instance("myUrl");
```

and when your done with it use:

```
browser.Close();
```

hope this helps. If you have any other questions I'll try to help.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of WatIn are you using

Watin has a specific dispose method for this job

```
browser.Dispose();
```